# Atmega328pb type casting errors

Tags: arduino-ide

I've created a custom pcb with a Atmega328pb cpu.
It's said to be binary compatible with Atmega32p, thus i flash it with my already functioning sketches that i've developed using an arduino.

The thing is that i have a `double` that i try to cast to `int` and when i do, it crashes the processor.

The code works perfectly fine on 328p so i'm wondering whether it could be a compiler issue, hardware issue, fuse settings issue.

```c
double globalDouble = 0.0;

void arne() {
  int stuff = globalDouble;
  // program execution halted…
}
```

The board manager does not include 328pb bit but https://www.pololu.com/ has board config for it, so has http://github.com/watterott/ATmega328PB-Testing, but they make no difference. Still halts. 
Any clues on how to move forward? I could ask the factory to replace it with a 328p but i'de rather have my already made products work.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you know it halts because of it? Have you tried to compare assembly for both MCU's? Does it even use the same version of compiler? Maybe it's just a compiler bug.

Comment: try with AVR boards package 1.6.21